# Definition of mean free time in the Drude model

Tags: terminology, definition

In the [Drude model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model) they derive a formule for the conductivity of a conductor.
I wonder though how the main free time $\tau$ is defined in this formula. 
Wikipedia says that it is "the average time between subsequent collisions". 
But I have two possible interpretations of this:

1. the average time an electron travels before colliding (which it seems to imply).
2. The average amount of time electrons have been travelling at a given time $t$ ($\tau$ will be substantially smaller in this definition).

The first definition seems to me how they describe it, while the second definition seems to be implied by the formulas. I wonder the same for "mean free path", which seems to be analogous.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a really good question, with a *mind-bending* answer. Check this out:

(A) Pick a random electron at a random time. How long (on average) do I need to wait until the next time it collides?

(B) Pick a random electron at a random time. How long (on average) has it been since the last time it collided?

(C) Pick a random electron that *just collided*. How long (on average) do I need to wait until the *next* time it collides?

(D) Pick a random electron that *just collided*. How long (on average) has it been since the *last* time it collided?

The answer is that **all four of these are the same**. (All four of them are what's called "mean free time".) It's mind-bending because it seems like (C) should be the *sum* of (A) plus (B), not the *same* as (A) and (B). But if you think about it, (C) and (A) *have* to be the same, because the fact that the electron just collided - something that happened in the past - cannot give any information about the statistics of what will happen to that electron in the *future*. We are assuming that collisions occur randomly! Similarly, (B) and (D) *have* to be the same. (A) and (B) have to be the same, obviously, because of time-reversal symmetry, and likewise (C) and (D) have to be the same.

Here's something that might help you come to peace with this apparent paradox (the so-called ["Inspection Paradox"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory#The_inspection_paradox)): An average where you **pick a random electron at a random time** is different than an average where you **pick a random collision-to-collision free trajectory**. (The former is relevant for (A-B), the latter is relevant for (C-D).) Compared to the former, the latter gives disproportionate weight to very short free trajectories. In other words, the ensemble of collision-to-collision free trajectories that you look at in (C) and (D) are, on average, *shorter* in duration than the ensemble of collision-to-collision free trajectories that you look at in (A) and (B).

Comment: You said that "the ensemble of collision-to-collision free trajectories that you look at in (C) and (D) are, on average, shorter in duration than the ensemble of collision-to-collision free trajectories that you look at in (A) and (B)." I can't really understand it. What does the "duration" mean?

Comment: "Duration" is not a technical jargon term, it's just a word that means "length of time".

Comment: Hi Steve, I really feel like your answer has something deep and awesome that I should be getting, but I still don't understand. If I go to the dentist once every year or so (the electrons collide on average every $\tau$). If you were to ask me at a random time in the year in about how long I'll go to the dentist, on average I'd answer that I'll go in a half a year (A). This will be equal to my (average) answer to the question: "How long has it been since you last went to the dentist (B)". However, if you knew that I went to the dentist yesterday, and you came and asked me:

Comment: "In about how long will you go to the dentist" - my answer will be: "In around a year" (C). And if you were to ask me: "When was the last time you went to the dentist" I'll answer that it was about a year ago (D). Those answers differ by a factor of 2. I know that what I'm missing between me going to the dentist on a consistent basis and the electrons crashing into atoms is that the electrons don't crash on a consistent basis. But I'm not sure how to intuitively explain it to myself  Thanks!